# How to make JSLint ignore pieces of code?

Tags: javascript, jslint

My php file has mainly several javascript functions which I wanted to debug. The file starts with:

```
/*ignore jslint start*/
<? Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
include('../country files/' . $_GET['country'] . '.php');
?>
/*ignore jslint end*/
  ...
  javascript code
```

Though, JSLint gives error on line 1!

Comment: JSLint is "The JavaScript Code Quality Tool". So instead of pasting PHP code, you should paste the JS code produced by that PHP.

Comment: @Oriol
My php file needs only some php variables in two JS functions, but all the other functions are just purely javascript written. It would be very useful to simply **ignore** pieces of code in JSLint

Answer (score 3):

You can change JSLint options for a few lines, with comments.

For example, JSLint will complain about you using [Underscore.JS](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/), because it isn't good practice to have underscores at the ends of variables names. But I can happily use Underscore's `each()` function by temporarily preventing [nomen](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options) warnings:

```
/*jslint nomen:true*/ // suppress dangling underscore warnings
_.each( ... ); // example use of Underscore.JS
/*jslint nomen:false*/ // re-enable dangling underscore warnings
```

However, there isn't a way to use comments to temporarily disable JSLint completely.

It is good practice to move your JavaScript out into separate files. Ideally, you shouldn't be running JSLint on HTML or PHP files, only on pure JavaScript files.

If you need to dynamically generate JavaScript code with PHP, then run JSlint on a sample of the output, of you like. Generally, you minimise the cases where this is necessary.

You could have PHP generate a small amount of JavaScript to establish operational context (e.g. a few global constants), and leave the rest of your front end functionality to separate pure JavaScript files.

Comment: can you kindly be more specific? What does option nomen do?

Comment: Do I need to insert my ignored code in-between _.each()

Comment: I updated the example, @user3116402, let me know if it needs further clarification.